# Login failure : 403 forbidden; When trying to access the Eucalyptus Cloud Using Netbeans(with Amazon API)

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, eucalyptus

I would like access my eucalyptus cloud using Amazon AWS.

For that, I have changed the EndPoint to my Cloud CC IP address (something like 172.
16.90.150:8773/services/Eucalyptus)

But, It is showing an error 403: forbidden

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hi make sure you are using proper access key and secret key to access your euca cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use some AWS client tools, with Eucalyptus. I assume you are using the AWS Java SDK, some versions of which can be used with Eucalyptus. When using this client you may find that you need to use a slightly different URL due to the way it signs requests, e.g.

```
http://172.16.90.150:8773/services/Eucalyptus/
```

So with a trailing "/".

The Eucalyptus wiki includes some information on [tool compatiblity](https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/AWS-compatibility).